# Failed to load image in react PDF CORS policy error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

Here Is My Like : [Image Link](https://cdn.flyfarint.com/WL/FFA1926/FFSA1008/companylogo.png)

I have been used cdn link in my react pdf but its actually showing cors policy error.

```
<Image
            style={{ border: "2px solid red", height: "70px" }}
            src={
              "https://cdn.flyfarint.com/WL/FFA1926/FFSA1008/companylogo.png"
            }
          />
```

But doesn't working. But if I get image from google or others its working. what is the problem or how can I solve this.

what is the problem and what is the way to solve.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 1):

this problem usually needs to be solved from the place where you pull the data. You need to write a code inside of the server for cors policy.
on front end side, you can use cors-policy plugin for this job.
[chrome-cors-policy-plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc).
Also, you can [check cors-policy details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).